# 150 psi dual pump pressure switch issue

Tags: plumbing, pump, water-tank, pressure

I have this pump (12v dc dual 150psi diaphragm pump). As you can see it has a built in pressure switch which I have disconnected because it does not pump water at all if it is connected - it turns on but no water is pumped. When I disconnect the switch as shown here, it pumps fine. So what might cause this?
[image: Water pump]

Secondly I have this pressure accumulator tank (50 psi working pressure), from what I can see, I connected the outlet of the pump to one end of the T and one end goes into the tank but the last end of the T has no water pressure at all. Should I use the valve the bottom of the tank to let some air out for it to start working?

[image]

Comment: Have you tested the switch to see if it's actually working? Are you sure you're below 50 PSI? It could be that it's cutting off at 50 PSI as it's supposed to be doing...

Comment: how do you know that it is a switch?

Comment: @FreeMan I checked the pump it says 8 bar cut off pressure...so thats around 116 psi, idk how this impacts anything I'm a complete noob at this.